# EDA: Enabling debug logs

Tags: debug-logs, npsp, education-data-architecture

I am working on creating some classes on top of EDA package. Inside the EDA package, there are some debug statements which is controlled by a field `Enable_Debug__c` on `Hierarchy Settings` custom settings. I have checked it, but still I don't see the debug statements in the logs generated when I am trying to create a contact (for say). I can see the logs that I am trying to print from my classes, but not the ones inside the EDA package.

Has anyone worked with EDA package? Is there is anything else I need to enable from my side?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see debug logs from Apex code inside any managed package, including EDA. This is part of the protection (including code IP protection) applied to all managed packages.

There's no way for end users to change this behavior.

EDA offers built-in error handling and logging for [asynchronous jobs only](https://powerofus.force.com/s/article/EDA-Configure-Error-Handling), which you can configure in EDA settings.